# drives letter changed to * after merging two drives with different cluster size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

i have 4 partitions in my main hdd. one of them has a cluster size of 2 MB and the others have a default of 4 KB:

- C: = windows 10
- D: = Empty {2mb cluster size}
- E: = my whole life
- F:

i booted in win PE and used EASEUS Partition master to merging D & E. but it stucked at 4% and after a few minutes program closed without any errors. then i opened explorer and noticed that D & E had disappeared. then opened EASEUS again and see D & E replaced with * and E has about 60GB data and D reduced from about 200GB to about 40GB. then again opened EASEUS and checked for bad sectors, results 0 bad sector. then again merged two drive but again crashed on 4%.

EASEUS iterface
[image: EASEUS iterface]

now how i can recover my whole life? do i need use chkdsk /f? does it dmages my data more?
i tested other programs like minitools and AOMEI too but they cant even merge two drives. and i noticed some apps like minitools cant detect properly drive with big cluster sizes (showed drive as unknown).
also in EASEUS when i choose Explore i cant see any folders in D and all my folders still showed in E but many files missed.
thanks

Update 1: after @DrMoishe Pippik suggestion in comments i created a backup of two drive in another disk with EASEUS Backup. and then used GetDataBack Pro 5.57 for recovering data from E. its now processing... but i noticed my drive letter backed and i can access them. now i see this data in D:

D & E:
[image: D & E]

as i said D was empty (only had that "2 delete Log Files.cmd"). you can see two folders are created, the second one is empty but the first one has about 70GB of data. i opened it and found that a lot of my data was in there. so i concluded that EASEUS didn't damage anything and only moved about 70% of the data to this new folder (or maybe im wrong and these folders were created by GetDataBack!?). also i opened some important txt files there and found no damage. so im gonna copy this folder and also data of E to another disk.any other suggestion is accepted.

Update 2: GetDataBack done! but i cant close this message:

[image: GetDataBack]

it says 98% done. so if two folders were created by GetDataBack, does that mean i lost 2% of my data?

Comment: Golden rule. Never attempt anything as dangerous as this without a backup.

Comment: because I resized many drives with these programs, so i trusted them.

Comment: Resizing is not the same as merging; but of course it works every time… until the time it doesn't. That's what backups are for - useless 99.999% of the time, because you don't need them. Absolutely vital 0.001%, because you're lost without one.

Comment: You can *try* to salvage data, perhaps a file or two at a time, or you can restore everything at once from the last full disk image. Before you do anything else, though, **make a full disk image now**, because any further attempt to change the disk will likely destroy some more data. See EASEUS:https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/free-windows-10-disk-imaging-software.html

Comment: That last message where you show it simply sitting there makes me think that you probably have bad sectors on the drive.  That might explain this whole problem.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas
Thanks for your suggestion, I checked those two drives for bad sectors the same day, but nothing was found. I want to create just one partition on my 1TB hard drive and then maybe check the whole hard drive for bad sectors.